# Storing output of a bash script for reuse

Tags: bash, shell-script

I made a script [Wall-d](https://github.com/ronniedroid/Wall-d) that sets the wallpaper for x. I want to save the output (the chosen Wallpaper and other options) in a variable that I can reuse later with a flag

For example,

```
xwallpaper --$option $wall
```

and the result is

```
xwallpaper --zoom $HOME/Pictures/mountain.png
```

Hoe can I store this info so that I can later use a flag to restore the last set wallpaper when I restart x, for example
In .xinitrc

```
Wall-d -r
```

should restore the last set wallpaper.

Hope I'm clear in what I'm asking. my Github repo for Wall-d is linked above if you need to see the code

Thank you in advance

PS: Please note that my question is not how to make the flag -r, but rather how to store the last output of the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your data on the disk if you want it to not get reset on reboot.

Use for example:

```bsh
CACHE_DIR=${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/wall-d
mkdir -p "$CACHE_DIR"
echo "$@" > "$CACHE_DIR/args"
```

Store the last wallpaper as a symlink:

```
ln -s "$wall" "$CACHE_DIR/wall"
```

Then you can use this symlink instead of a path to an image for your restore command.

Comment: This is not working for me. when I open the "args" file, it is empty.

Comment: Create a minimal script with just `echo "$@" >/tmp/file` and invoke it with arguments. You will see that the code I’ve given is not wrong. We will not debug your script.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't say your code is wrong, I'm just saying, it didn't work with my script, which means I have a problem with my script. Just wanted to let you know that it didn't work for me. Than you again